# Careers is too spammy

Tags: discussion, jobs, email

Careers sends an email every three months that says it "noticed you haven't updated your profile in a while. Have you changed jobs, blah blah blah?"

This is way too spammy of a reminder. As an employer, I summarily dispose of resumes where the candidate has been at a new job every year, let alone every three months. Once a year would be the minimum I think is suitable for this kind of reminder.

I clicked the only sensible option, which was "opt out," but from the resulting page, it's not clear if that just stopped that one type of emails, or everything on careers, or everything from all stackexchange sites. I only want to stop that one type of unnecessary reminder.

Comment: I don't ever remember receiving an email like that, but I'd agree it's rather useless and unnecessary...

Comment: I guess that's an employer thing only, I have never seen such an email yet.

Comment: I tend to keep my profile up to date every few weeks, just adding interesting bits about what I'm doing at my current position. Then my CV is basically ready when and if I need it (which is why I like Careers). I think a lot of people use it that way, which is probably why nobody has complained about that rather obnoxious reminder yet :) Anyway, +1 to getting rid of it.

Comment: I get them quite often as well. I suppose you get them if you sign up for Careers but then don't really use it.

Comment: I don't mind the functionality being there, but there should be a simple way to change the interval, or to turn the reminders off completely.

Answer (score 6):

There's a lot more to Careers than adding a new job.  I can't think of a time in my career where I haven't done *something* noteworthy in three months: finished a project at work, answered some new questions on SO, created a new project on GitHub, read an interesting book, etc.  There's almost always something worth updating, even if it's just to add a new bullet point under my current job.

If you're searchable, employers want to see that your profile is not out of date.  A quick look over your profile every three months to make sure it's up to date doesn't seem excessive to me.  And, as you found, there's an easy way to opt out of the email.

Comment: +1, I had never really considered using Careers this way.

Answer (score 5):

I am not using Careers, but if I were a potential employer I would like the data to be as accurate as possible. If most profiles become outdated, then I'd move elsewhere, or sort by last update date and ignore older profiles. Sure, not many people change jobs *every* 3 months, but many people have changed jobs or responsibilities during the past 3 months. Some of them will have forgotten to update their profile. (What does the "blah blah blah" say?)

I think that's what this is about: just trying to ensure things indeed haven't changed. I wouldn't mind receiving such reminder if I were a user, but I surely wouldn't mind if I were a potential employer.